# Javafx Text Based Game, Button-switch statement

Tags: string, button, javafx, switch-statement, scenebuilder

Hi I'm trying to create a text based game with the new javafx features. 
I am having difficulties making my buttons assign a value and then use that value in a switch statement.
Anybody have any suggestions?
Or if anyone knows any tutorials on text-based games with javafx let me know.

I think the problem may be that when the method that contains the switch statement is called, the switch statement is performed on whichever values are already assigned and then the call is over.
Which is not what I am trying to achieve.
Here is my code in the controller class:

```
package sample.view;

import java.io.*;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import sample.Main;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import sample.chapter1;

public class gameScreenController {
    public Button button0;
    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;
    public TextArea textArea;
    public ImageView image1;
    public ImageView image2;
    public String question = "0";
    public String choice = "";
    public Label label;

    /*
    this method is used when the user clicks button1
     */


    public gameScreenController() {
    }

    @FXML
    public void button0() {
        textArea.setText(setTextArea("ch1Start"));

        button1.setText("what a beautiful poem");
        button2.setText("She know nothing. She got nothing");
        button3.setText("...");
        button0.setVisible(false);
        chapter1();
    }

    @FXML
    public void button1() {
        choice = "c1";
        out.println("c1");



    }

    /*
    this method is used when the user clicks button2
     */
    @FXML
    public void button2() {
        choice = "c2";
        out.println("c2");
    }

    /*
    this method is used when the user clicks button3
     */
    @FXML
    public void button3() {
        choice = "c3";
        out.println("c3");

    }

    @FXML
    public String setTextArea(String fileName) {

        String line;
        String content = null;

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(line);
                 content += line + '\n';
            }
            buffer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            out.println("Unable to open file " + fileName + ".");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            out.println("error reading file " + fileName + ".");
        }
        return content;
    }



    public void chapter1 () {

        switch (question) {
            case "0":
                switch (choice) {
                    case "c1":
                        textArea.setText(setTextArea("hi"));
                        out.println("it worked");
                        question = "1";
                        break;
                    case "c2":
                        out.println("it worked");
                        break;
                    case "c3":
                        out.println("it worked");
                        break;


                } break;
            case "1":
                break;
   } }}
```

This is the code I am trying to replicate into javafx:

```
 public class ChoiceHandler implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // takes in button click -> youtChoice variable
        String yourChoice = event.getActionCommand();

        switch (position)
        {
            case "townGate":
                switch(yourChoice)
                {
                    case "c1": flirt(); break;
                    case "c2": talkGuard(); break;
                    case "c3": leave(); break;
                    case "c4": break;
                }
            case "talkguard":
                switch (yourChoice)
                {
                    case "c1": townGate(); break;

                }
            case "flirt":
                switch (yourChoice)
                {
                    case "c1": townGate(); break;

                }
            case "outside":
                switch (yourChoice)
                {
                    case "c1": townGate(); break;
                    case "c2": break;
                    case "c3": break;
                    case "c4": break;
                }


        }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exacly think when you say 'assigning a value to a button'.

There are multiple options:

- as you already wrote it in the code, you could use a String or Integer. You change the value of this variable when the button is clicked
- You extend the Button class, e.g. :

  ```
  public class MyButton extends javafx.scene.control.Button {

  private String value;

  public MyButton() {
      super();
  }

  public MyButton(String text) {
      super(text);
  }

  public void setValue(String newValue) {
      value = newValue;
  }

  public String getValue() {
      return value;
  }
  }
  ```

You can learn a lot about javafx in the online tutorials from oracle: 
[Click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm)

Comment: I'm not trying to change the value of the button. I am trying to change the variable "choice" and how that variable interacts with my switch statement.